# ¿Como detectar el doble clic en botón BACK de mi celular en Delphi 10.2 Tokyo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo

Estoy desarrollando una app Android con Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, en la ya pude detectar el boton back con el siguiente codigo:

```
if Key = vkHardwareBack then
begin
  showmessage('Botón BACK presionado!');
  key := 0; 
end;
```

Este código lo implemento en el evento OnKeyUp de mi forma principal, pero ¿como puedo detectar un doble clic en el botón BACK para que mi app se cierre?, espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde logro recordar, no hay ningún evento que se lance automáticamente para el "doble clic" del botón back.

Pero es algo que no es tan difícil de implementar por tu cuenta.

Suponiendo que tienes 2 acciones que quieres ejecutar, una cuando se da un clic "simple" y otra cuando se da un clic "doble", puedes hacerlo fácilmente con un timer, que será el que definirá la *sensibilidad* de tu aplicación al doble clic, yo lo dejaría, digamos, en unos 300 milisegundos. Entonces, tu evento OnKeyUp luciría como este:

```
begin
  if Key = vkHardwareBack then
  begin
    if tmrBackButtonUnClic.Enabled then
    begin
      tmrBackButtonUnClic.Enabled := False;
      ShowMessage('Doble clic en el botón BACK');
    end
    else 
      tmrBackButtonUnClic.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Y tu evento OnTimer del tmrBackButtonUnClic, así:

```
begin
  tmrBackButtonUnClic.Enabled := False;
  ShowMessage('Clic simple en el botón BACK');
end;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias intentare esta solución, pensé que si había algún evento para ser invocado automáticamente.